# Is it possible to make animated splash screen to solve the white screen problem during loading the resources?

Tags: react-native

Is their any way to make a animated splash screen and solves the white screen problem during loading the resources.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue in a bit detail? Like if you have already added a native splash screen (instead of a splash component), then the splash screen should be appearing instead of white screen

Comment: Need more detail than that.  If you are just interested in updating your splash screen from the current white background to something custom, lots of examples online on how to do that.